# Error at .catch((err) => { at first paranthesis

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Bot sends a message saying user was banned and if the bot tries to ban someone with the same permissions, it gives the error message however I can't get the catch error to send the error message. Also wondering how I can have the user's name after a ban in the message.

```
message.channel.send('User has been banned').catch
                        .catch((err) => {
                            return message.reply("I am unable ban that member")
                            .catch;
                        });
```

Comment: Why are you typing `.catch` then `.catch()`? Catch is a callback method, you simply need to do `.catch(err => console.error(err))` or `.catch(console.error)` for short.

Comment: Look at the [MDN Documentation on Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: So should it look something like this?
`message.channel.send('User has been banned')
                            .catch(console.error)
                             {
                            return message.reply("I am unable ban that member")
                            .catch;
                        };`
Sorry if my questions sound stupid. I'm fairly new to js

Comment: The only catch that makes sense is the one that's syntax highlighted

Comment: `catch()` is a callback, you do all of your error handling inside the function. Look at the link I've sent

Comment: This is what I have but now it gives both outputs for an error message
`memberTarget.kick()
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err); // error log
                    message.reply("I am unable kick that member");                           
                  });
                message.channel.send('User has been kicked');
                
            }`
@Lil Peep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Promise#catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) accepts a callback. Generally, it is better to log the error rather than throwing it away. This can be simply done by using [console.error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error). It will work both on web and node application.

```js
message.channel.send('User has been banned')
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err); // log error
    message.reply("I am unable ban that member");                           
  });
```

Comment: In case you need to put successful state, you need to add `.then`. In your case,
`memberTarget.kick().then(() => msg.channel.send('User has been kicked')).catch((err) => { console.err(err); msg.reply('Im unable to kick that member'); })`